Why am I getting TS7006 for my union of function types?
I am trying to use a union of function types with different parameters, but I am getting error TS7006 ("Parameter '...' implicitly has an 'any' type.") when using the parameter.
I do not understand why that is.

In general, assume I am working with these two interfaces:
interface IIntf {
    x: number;
}

interface IExtendedIntf extends IIntf {
    y: number;
}

Now, each of my individual function types should consume one of these.
As long as only one of the function types expects a parameter, all is well:
type Func1<T> = () => T;
type Func2<T> = (ctx: IExtendedIntf) => T;

type SomeFunc<T> = Func1<T> | Func2<T>;

const val: SomeFunc<string> = ctx => {
    return `test${ctx.x}`;
};

No errors.
But as soon as Func1 expects a different argument:
type Func1<T> = (ctx: IIntf) => T;
type Func2<T> = (ctx: IExtendedIntf) => T;

type SomeFunc<T> = Func1<T> | Func2<T>;

const val: SomeFunc<string> = ctx => {
    return `test${ctx.x}`;
};

the ctx parameter in the lambda function on the third to last line is pointed out as erroneous:

Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)

Why? Does the compiler absolutely have to know which actual function type I am using?
And is there anything I could do to help it along with that, without forcing users to write an explicit parameter type such as ctx: IIntf or ctx: IExtendedIntf each time? In many cases, they would actually be totally fine with just knowing that ctx is of type IIntf & IExtendedIntf.

Please do not suggest to disable type-checking or allow the use of any, either globally or locally. That is not a solution.
Also, the general question on error TS7006, "Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type", does not deal with the concrete question I am asking here.
